# DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: server, datatables, internals

Here, i am using bootstrap datatables to load my data from database. But when i open the page it shows the error and in console it shows ---Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).. How to solve this problem..Please help

Comment: Solve what ever causing the http 500 error code.  Not to be arrogant, this is just the only answer anyone can give.  Your problem has nothing to do with DataTables, and there is literally millions of potential reasons why you get a 500 from your server.  Typically it is caused by some error in the server script code or in the server config, for example a bad .htaccess.

Comment: So, david you are saying , this problem  has nothing to do with DataTables but it says DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Ajax error. What do you think about it?? Thanks

Comment: I think that DataTables gracefully handle an error that is not caused by DataTables itself. You have a problem with your server script, it can be anything from a PHP script not being closed properly to a complete misconfiguration.  I would take a look at the script that is called via AJAX.

Comment: Hello, here is the link of my script and sorry for being late: https://gist.github.com/1233ww/9f6e7931958303f8856bdad5e991611a

Comment: this is the client side script. The error you experience come from serverside, probably the script `fetch.php` ...When you have fixed that, consider to add a column / columnDefs section to your DT initialization.

Comment: Try adding your backend script after removing private info like usernames and passwords.